# Reference voltage for a comparator

Tags: voltage, comparator, homework, 741-opamp

The question is to determine the reference voltage for the comparator shown in the figure below:
[image]

After I understood that by the reference voltage is meant the voltage at the negative terminal, then I came up with this solution:

The voltage drop at R1 should be 10 V and the voltage drop through R2 should be 5V. The voltage at the nod ( between R1 and R2) should be 5V. And that voltage goes through the R2 and it also represents the reference voltage that goes through the negative terminal.

I am not sure about this solution. Can someone help me if this approach is correct? Or should I represent that reference voltage using the Vin also?

Comment: Homework questions without an effort to solve don’t get very far here. Don’t be surprised if your question gets closed.

Comment: @hacktastical I am not asking for solution but to help me understand what is meant by reference voltage. Should I find the value of Vin or Vout.

Comment: The reference voltage is the voltage at the negative terminal of the comparator

Comment: @JohnD what value should Vin suppose to be? Should it be the same as the negative terminal

Comment: Your calculation re negative input terminal is correct. | The comparator compares Vin with the reference voltage so Vin can be any legitimate voltage allowed by the datasheet. This varies with device but is typically about +/- 13V for a +/- 15V supply. || The purpose of the comparator is to set Vout  to a value that indicates whether Vion is above or below Vout. You can determine what polarity Vout will have for various value of Vin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation and reasoning re negative input terminal is correct.

The comparator compares Vin with the reference voltage so Vin can be any legitimate voltage allowed by the datasheet. This varies with device but is typically about +/- 13V for a +/- 15V supply.

The purpose of the comparator is to set Vout  to a value that indicates whether Vin is above or below Vout. You can determine what polarity Vout will have for various value of Vin.